# Cucumber is Overriding my Override

Tags: ruby, cucumber, overriding, require, operator-precedence

I am looking to override puts to include a timestamp for all of my Cucumber step definitions. I have done this with a 'require' of a 'string_addons.rb' file which redefines puts to add the timestamp and then calls super(timestamped_str).

My problem is that rb_world.rb also overrides puts and has precedence over my override. Knowing that in Ruby the most recent override is what is used I require my 'string_addons.rb' again just above where the puts call is made. Unfortunately the puts from rb_world is still used.

Answer (score 0):

require keeps track of whether a file has already been included and will not load it a second time. This is why nothing is happening on your second require.

Comment: Thanks, I switched to 'load()' and am still having the same problem.